# Nodejs Array keeps distributing array over multiple lines

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, insert, formatting

To keep this short, i m working on a small discord bot. The bot is supposed to grab a servers banlist and then put it into its database. The problem is, to make a bulk insert, you appearently need an array that is stuctured like this

```
[
  ["blah 1", "bluh 1"],
  ["blah 2", "bluh 2"]
]
```

The problem that i m facing is, it distorts the formatting of the array for some reason

```
[
  ["blah 1", "bluh 1"],
  [
    "blah 1", 
    "bluh 1"
  ],
]
```

This is the code i use to create the array

```
list.forEach(element => {
    if(element.reason === null){ var reason = "No reason Given"}else{ var reason = element.reason}
    var userArray = [
        element.user.id,
        element.user.username,
        element.user.discriminator,
        reason,
        element.user.bot
    ]
    banArray.push(userArray)
})
```

Comment: you may need to expound further, the 1st and 2nd example or the array you provided are exactly in the same format, just differs in how it's being written/code.

Comment: Tip for shortening the reason: `element.reason || 'No reason Given'` will do the same as the if statement at the top of the `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to put this short again (its 4:11 am here right now, and i m lacking a lot of sleep). I found the problem i was having. I tried to use an array in my prepared statement while putting the unknown value into brackets.

```
queryStmt = "INSERT INTO tbl_bans (dtUserId, dtUserName, dtDiscriminator, dtReason, dtBot) VALUES (?)";
```

Notice the (?). The problem is, that i simply didnt look correctly at the code sample, and overlooked that there were no () around the ? in the sample.